If i delete a customized audio tool in Editor.js, how can you also delete the audio files from the folder?
Front End - ReactJs
BackEnd - Laravel
Im using EditorJs https://editorjs.io/
I have customized Audio Tool..
class CustomAudioPlayer  {

    data: any;
    api: any;
    editorRef: any;
    constructor({data, api}) {
        this.data = data;
        this.api = api;
        this.editorRef = api.editor;
    }

    static get toolbox() {
        return {
            icon: '<svg>...</svg>',
            title: 'Audio Player',
        };
    }


    render() {
        console.log("this.editorRef");
        console.log(this.editorRef);
        const optionValues = {
            'to Meeting Notes': 'meeting_notes',
            'as Summary': 'summarize',
            'Full Text': 'convert_to_text'
        };
        const container = document.createElement('div');

        container.classList.add('audio-player', 'flex', 'absolute', 'item-center', 'justify-between', 'relative', 'my-3');

         // Create the audio player
    const audioPlayer = document.createElement('audio');
    audioPlayer.controls = true;
    audioPlayer.src = this.data.url;
    container.appendChild(audioPlayer);


        const convertButton = document.createElement('button');
        convertButton.innerText = 'Transcribe';
        convertButton.classList.add('audioplayer_button_convert');

        const icon = document.createElement('i');
        icon.className = 'pi pi-sync mr-2 opacity-60 convert_to_icon_editor';

        // Insert the icon before the text in the button
        convertButton.insertBefore(icon, convertButton.firstChild);

        container.appendChild(convertButton);


        // Create the dropdown menu
                const dropdownMenu = document.createElement('div');
                dropdownMenu.classList.add('dropdown-menu');
                dropdownMenu.style.display = 'none'; // Initially hide the menu

                // Function to position the dropdown below the convert button



                // Create sub-options
                const options = ['to Meeting Notes', 'as Summarize', 'Full Text'];
                options.forEach(optionText => {
                    const option = document.createElement('div');
                    option.innerText = optionText;
                    option.classList.add('dropdown-option');
                    option.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        // Handle sub-option click here
                        const selectedValue = optionValues[optionText];
                        this.handleConvertToText(this.data.url, convertButton, selectedValue);
                        console.log(`Selected option: ${optionText}`);
                        dropdownMenu.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the menu after selection
                    });
                    dropdownMenu.appendChild(option);
                });

                // Append the close button in the top right corner of the dropdown menu
                const closeButton = document.createElement('button');
                closeButton.innerText = 'X';
                closeButton.classList.add('close-button-transcribe-editor');
                closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    dropdownMenu.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the menu when the close button is clicked
                });
                dropdownMenu.appendChild(closeButton);

                // Append the dropdown menu to the container
                container.appendChild(dropdownMenu);

                // Position the dropdown when the convert button is clicked
                convertButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    dropdownMenu.style.display = dropdownMenu.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

                });


        return container;
    }

    save() {

        return {
            url: this.data.url
        };
    }

    async handleConvertToText(audio_url, button, sub_option) {
        // Your logic to convert audio to text
        button.innerText = 'Transcribing...';
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        console.log(token);
        const icon = document.createElement('i');
        icon.className = 'pi pi-sync mr-2 opacity-60 convert_to_icon_editor';

        // Insert the icon before the text in the button
        button.insertBefore(icon, button.firstChild);
        button.disabled = true;

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                "api/chat/get_convert_editor_audio_to_text",
                {
                    url: audio_url,
                    option: sub_option,
                    editor_id : localStorage.getItem("editor_id")
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                    },
                }


            );

            if(response.data.status == "200")
            {
                let convertedText = response.data.chats;
                let token = response.data.token;
                let request = {
                    provider: 1,
                    debit_token: token,
                    lead_id: null,
                };

                makeAiTokenEntry(request)
                    .then((response) => {})
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Error retrieving accounts:", error);
                    });

                 this.api.blocks.insert('paragraph', { text: convertedText });

                  button.innerText = 'Transcribe';
                 button.disabled = false; // Re-enable the button
                 const icon = document.createElement('i');
                 icon.className = 'pi pi-sync mr-2 opacity-60 convert_to_icon_editor';

                 // Insert the icon before the text in the button
                 button.insertBefore(icon, button.firstChild);
            }


        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error converting audio to text", error);
            button.innerText = 'Transcribe';
            button.disabled = false; // Re-enable the button
            const icon = document.createElement('i');
            icon.className = 'pi pi-sync mr-2 opacity-60 convert_to_icon_editor';

            // Insert the icon before the text in the button
            button.insertBefore(icon, button.firstChild);
        }
    }
}

When I attempt to delete an audio block from the Editor, it should also delete that specific audio file from the folder. However, currently, when I press delete audio, it only removes the audio from the editor, not from the folder.

hi if i am understanding and rading example correctly  you are uploading/transcribing audio file.  When You delete audio block from editor you want to delete file from some folder  -  i am not sure from which folder but i will assume that is some folder on backend server where you have uploaded audio file for processing.
it seems that editor.js does not have well  defined delete listener  when  deleting some blocks look at this discussion Does it have a delete listener to delete image after I clicked remove from toolbar ?
but what could be utilised lifecycle-hooks especially removed
if you add removed hook on your block
  removed(){
    console.log(':::: REMOVEEEED :::::', this);
  }

in my example i am getting following log (from image block):

{
    "data": {
        "url": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/21/53/blue-2705642_1280.jpg"
    },
    "api": {
        "blocks": {},
        "caret": {},
        "events": {},
        "listeners": {},
        "notifier": {},
        "sanitizer": {},
        "saver": {},
        "selection": {},
        "styles": {
            "block": "cdx-block",
            "inlineToolButton": "ce-inline-tool",
            "inlineToolButtonActive": "ce-inline-tool--active",
            "input": "cdx-input",
            "loader": "cdx-loader",
            "button": "cdx-button",
            "settingsButton": "cdx-settings-button",
            "settingsButtonActive": "cdx-settings-button--active"
        },
        "toolbar": {},
        "inlineToolbar": {},
        "tooltip": {},
        "i18n": {},
        "readOnly": {
            "isEnabled": false
        },
        "ui": {
            "nodes": {
                "wrapper": {},
                "redactor": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "wrapper": {}
}

you can utilise it to make api call to remove specific file or something similar ?

appreciates your try
